# kendo Treelist keeps telling no records to Display

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, treelist, kendo-treelist

I´m intending to use some kendo controls from telerik and I started playing with the Treelist control. I´m doing this with Visual Studio 2013 VB or C#.

The plan is to create a webservice that sends some (serialized) data and the user has to manually press a button which is linked to a $Ajax request that POSTS for the data. That data should be passed to the treelist.

But whatever I try it keeps telling me: `No Records to Display`

Questions:

1 Why is the sample I provided not working. I copied almost literally one of the demo´s.

2 Do you need a seprate datasource or can you put the data direct in the treelist as well?

Thanks in advance.

Rick (NL)

Sample:

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
      var dataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
         data: [
             { "Item": "Item0", "id": 0, "ParentId": null },
             { "Item": "Item1", "id": 1, "ParentId": 0 },
             { "Item": "Item2", "id": 2, "ParentId": 1 },
             { "Item": "Item3", "id": 3, "ParentId": 1 },
             { "Item": "Item4", "id": 4, "ParentId": null },
             { "Item": "Item5", "id": 5, "ParentId": null },
             { "Item": "Item6", "id": 6, "ParentId": 5 },
             { "Item": "Item7", "id": 7, "ParentId": 5 },
             { "Item": "Item8", "id": 8, "ParentId": 7 },
             { "Item": "Item9", "id": 9, "ParentId": 7 }
         ],
         schema: {
             model: {
                 id: "id",
                 expanded: true
             }
         }
     });

     $("#treelist").kendoTreeList({
         dataSource: dataSource,
         height: 540,
         columns: [
             { field: "Item" },
             { field: "id" },
             { field: "ParentId" }
         ]
     });
 });

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is down to a simple typo the "ParentId" needs to be parentId (note lowercase p).

see this dojo for a working version.

http://dojo.telerik.com/uWaSO

I've fallen foul of this before.

Answer (score 13):

parentId also needs to be null if it's the top-level record. That really tripped me up.

Comment: This resolved my issue and is very important. If the top level record does not have null for parentId it will show No Records To Display, even if everything else is correct.

Answer (score 6):

@user4659712 yes, you can define the schema. parentId can be anything as long as you tell through the schema:

```
     vm.treeListDataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
         data: organizations,
         schema: {
             model: {
                 id: "Id",
                 fields: {
                     Id: { type: "number", nullable: false },
                     parentId: { field: "OverliggendeId", nullable: true }
                 },
                 expanded: true
             }
         },
         pageSize: 20
     });
```

Comment: for some reason, mapping the 'parentId' field using the schema doesn't work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: worked for me when i tried it. To work with the data above only the parentId 'field' needs changing.

Answer (score 2):

Lets not forget the 'parentId' field on the model definition. We don't have to change the JSON properties that way (ParentId needs describing in fields as well though):

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
        data: [
            { Id: 1, Name: "test", ParentId: null },
            { Id: 2, Name: "test 2", ParentId: 1 }
        ],
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "Id",
                parentId: "ParentId",
                fields: {
                    Name: { field: "Name", type: "string" },
                    StoreCount: { field: "StoreCount", type: "number" },
                    ParentId: { field: "ParentId", nullable: true }
                },
                expanded: true
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: So, the key really was to have the field definition for custom parent id ( in this case "ParentId") property defined in "fields" in the schema. I'd missed defining it. So, setting ParentId: { field: "ParentId", nullable: true } did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Does anyone know if you can specify a database column with a different name to be the parentid? For example, my table has node_id and parent_node_id.